# Erase PowerPoint pen drawing and annotation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to programmatically erase user's pen drawing and annotation over slides in PowerPoint 2003/2007/2010 as an alternative to sending "E" keystroke.

I have found that `SlideShowView.EraseDrawing` only erases lines made by `SlideShowView.DrawLine`.

Sample code:

`PowerPoint.Application.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run.View.EraseDrawing`

Thanks for your answers! **rjobidon**

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to delete the pen drawing after they've stopped the slide show and chosen to retain the drawing? In that case, invoke the EraseInkOnSlide function below on any slide you want to erase drawings from.

```
Sub TestMe()
    EraseInkOnSlide ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
End Sub

Sub EraseInkOnSlide(oSl As Slide)
' Erases any INK shapes drawn by the user and 
' retained when the user quits the slide show
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim x As Long
    With oSl.Shapes
    For x = .Count To 1 Step -1
        If .Item(x).Type = 23 Then
            .Item(x).Delete
        End If
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I suspect you'd hve to drop out of slide show mode momentarily then return to the current slide in slideshwo mode in order to get this to work in slide show mode; PPT apparently doesn't consider the ink shapes part of the slide's shapes collection until the user has ended the show and elected to keep the shapes.  Weird.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your answer! Yes, we want to erase pen drawing in live mode, before changing slide or ending slide show.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the user the option of keeping or deleting the ink, then goes back to the original slide in slide show view.  STILL not what you're after, really, but it's as close as I've been able to get so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Long
    x = SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex

    With SlideShowWindows(1)
        .View.Exit
    End With

    With ActivePresentation
        .SlideShowSettings.Run
    End With

    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (x)

End Sub
```